# VBA, Excel 2007, Inconsistant Runtime Error 13 on various user accounts

Tags: vba, excel, type-conversion, runtime-error

I am a coop student at a factory and I was developing a VBA program in excel for the operators to use for data collection. The program works perfectly on my bosses and my user account, but is throwing runtime errors when the operators try to use it; specifically, it is throwing a runtime error 13 (type mismatch) when I know the data is correctly entered.

Something as simple as Msgbox Cdec("26.1"), or Msgbox Cdbl("26.1") is throwing the mismatch error on the operators account, but it runs perfectly on my account (on the same computer). I initially thought it could have been to keyboard settings/language settings so I tried playing with the settings while entering data, but nothing changed. I checked to make sure that all of the same libraries were being referenced in the excel options.

I am completely at a loss and don't know where this problem is coming from. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the issue is. Because I reside in Ottawa, Canada which is bilingual, some of the operators had French regional settings. This caused them to use a comma instead of a period for a decimal point. By simply changing this property in the windows "regional settings", I was able to resolve the problem.